# Issue with TableOne and gtsummary when Handling Small Values in Variables

Tags: r, statistics

Good evening!

I'm currently encountering a challenge with TableOne (and gtsummary) when attempting to create a table with variables of very small orders of magnitude, such as e−8e−8. It seems that TableOne is treating these values as zero due to their minimal size.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
# library(gtsummary)
library(tableone)
data(iris)
iris$rands <- 1e-9 * runif(n = nrow(iris))
tableone::CreateTableOne(data = iris) |> print()
```

gives

```
                          
                           Overall     
  n                         150        
  Sepal.Length (mean (SD)) 5.84 (0.83) 
  Sepal.Width (mean (SD))  3.06 (0.44) 
  Petal.Length (mean (SD)) 3.76 (1.77) 
  Petal.Width (mean (SD))  1.20 (0.76) 
  Species (%)                          
     setosa                  50 (33.3) 
     versicolor              50 (33.3) 
     virginica               50 (33.3) 
  rands (mean (SD))        0.00 (0.00)
```

In this example, I would like to display the actual mean value of the variable, even though it is very small, instead of it being reduced to 0.

Any suggestions on how to handle this issue with TableOne or gtsummary would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `?print.TableOne()`:

```
# library(gtsummary)
library(tableone)
data(iris)
iris$rands <- 1e-9 * runif(n = nrow(iris))
tableone::CreateTableOne(data = iris) |> print(contDigits = 10L)
```

gives

```
                          
                           Overall                    
  n                                 150               
  Sepal.Length (mean (SD)) 5.8433333333 (0.8280661280)
  Sepal.Width (mean (SD))  3.0573333333 (0.4358662849)
  Petal.Length (mean (SD)) 3.7580000000 (1.7652982333)
  Petal.Width (mean (SD))  1.1993333333 (0.7622376690)
  Species (%)                                         
     setosa                          50 (33.3)        
     versicolor                      50 (33.3)        
     virginica                       50 (33.3)        
  rands (mean (SD))        0.0000000005 (0.0000000003)
```

They are not reduced to zero. Instead they are not displayed due to the default value of `contDigits` in `print.TableOne()`.

Comment: Oh, thank you! Weirdly I didnt know about the consulting the specific methods for objects. I modified too the formatOptions to display it in scientific notation, but yet it seems to keep the adicional (unnecesary) decimal digits. Would you know if there is a fix to that? Consulting the print.TableOne seems that digits its not availab,e and when I modify the first contDigits it reduces it to 0 again.

tableone::CreateTableOne(data = iris) %>%  print(contDigits = 15L, formatOptions= list(scientific = TRUE))

Comment: This is another question. And not reproducible from what you have presented to us. I think my post answers your question. Anyway, if you do not find any solution, just mutiply respective columns (variables) by a constant, and report your approach.

Comment: The explanation to `formatOptions` links to `format()` which under the explanation of `...` links to `prettyNum()`. There are plenty of options, e.g., list(zero.print = NULL). Scientific notation is nothing you have mentioned in your Q.